# Integrate Apache ACE with Equinox

Tags: apache, osgi, provisioning, equinox, apache-ace

I've read in the documentations of Apache Ace 2 that it works with Equinox OSGi targets as well, but I can't find out how to configure it. I am aware there is already p2 for Equinox but I also want to integrate it with the Ace software.

I've found somewhere that I should edit *managementagent* bundle, if that's true still don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary release of Apache ACE ships with:

1. An executable jar that contains Apache Felix and the management agent. It can be found in the server-allinone/store folder and is called ace-launcher.jar
2. A "development" target in the target/ folder that can be used to for development/testing and pre-installs a shell, logging and the management agent.

Neither gives you Equinox out of the box.

However, if you checkout the ACE sources, there is a project called org.apache.ace.agent.launcher which creates two jar files:

1. felix.bnd which creates the ace-launcher.jar mentioned above and embeds Apache Felix
2. base.bnd which relies on the standardized launcher API of OSGi and will bootstrap the first framework it finds on the classpath

So, you can either use the artifact generated by base.bnd and put Equinox on your classpath, or take felix.bnd and modify it so it will run equinox instead.

By the way, we would be happy to accept such work as a patch so we can provide this out of the box.